# define function like auth::route

Tags: laravel

I want to define function like `Auth::routes()`

```
//its worked :
public static function oneroute()
{
        return Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@index');
}
```

but its not worked (when i,m return multi routes) :

```
public static function RouteProfile()
    {
        return function () {
            Route::group(['prefix'=>'profile'],function (){
                Route::get('/','ProfileController@index')->name('person.profile.index');
                Route::get('/session','ProfileController@sessions')->name('person.profile.sessions');
                Route::get('/password','ProfileController@password')->name('person.profile.password');
                Route::post('/password','ProfileController@change_password')->name('person.profile.password');
                Route::get('/create','ProfileController@create')->name('person.profile.create');
                Route::post('/create','ProfileController@store')->name('person.profile.store');
                Route::get('/edit','ProfileController@edit')->name('person.profile.edit');
                Route::post('/edit','ProfileController@update')->name('person.profile.update');
            });
        };

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where does this code exist? where is it being called? you have a closure there, what is executing that closure?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a small error

```
public static function RouteProfile()
{
    return Route::group(['prefix'=>'profile'], function () {
        Route::get('/','ProfileController@index')->name('person.profile.index');
        Route::get('/session','ProfileController@sessions')->name('person.profile.sessions');
        Route::get('/password','ProfileController@password')->name('person.profile.password');
        Route::post('/password','ProfileController@change_password')->name('person.profile.password');
        Route::get('/create','ProfileController@create')->name('person.profile.create');
        Route::post('/create','ProfileController@store')->name('person.profile.store');
        Route::get('/edit','ProfileController@edit')->name('person.profile.edit');
        Route::post('/edit','ProfileController@update')->name('person.profile.update');
    });
}
```

You don't need to put function after return, you can directly return the Route::group

And reading the docs for laravel 7 an optimized solution should be:

```
public static function RouteProfile()
{
    Route::prefix('profile')->name('person.profile.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/','ProfileController@index')->name('index');
        Route::get('/session','ProfileController@sessions')->name('sessions');
        Route::get('/password','ProfileController@password')->name('password');
        Route::post('/password','ProfileController@change_password')->name('password');
        Route::get('/create','ProfileController@create')->name('create');
        Route::post('/create','ProfileController@store')->name('.store');
        Route::get('/edit','ProfileController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::post('/edit','ProfileController@update')->name('update');
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't even think you need to return anything. Does the second solution work for you?